# Джанго 2.0 Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns

Tags: python, django

> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:  admin/ mainApp/ wubwub/  The empty path
>   didn't match any of these.

Вот, что в самом mysite\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('mainApp/', include('mainApp.urls')),
    path('wubwub/', include('wubwub.urls')),
]
```

Это mysite\mainApp\urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('mainApp/', views.index, name='index')
]
```

mysite\mainApp\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):

    return render(request, 'mainApp/homePage.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The empty path didn't match any of these.

Судя по ошибке вы запросили `/`, но у вас нет обработчика для этого URL.

Comment: Спасибо, вы меня направили в нужную сторону. Заменил в обоих urls.py 'mainApp/' на ' ' и всё работает.